# How to group by two columns

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I'd tired `group by week,day`, it didn't give me the correct result

Here is the table: weekDay

```
week    day   
-----------
 1       1         
 1       1         
 1       2         
 2       1         
 2       1         
 2       1  
 2       2         
 2       2
```

and expected result:

```
week    day     count
---------------------
1         1       2   
1         2       1
2         1       3
2         2       2
```

How to get the result above by using `group by` or other ways?

Comment: Hint:  `GROPU BY week, day`.

Comment: Show us  your tried code.

Comment: Sorry. I try to print out the result, I found the clause is correct, I made a mistake when inserting into database.

Answer (score 3):

Use following SQL query to retrieve result

```
SELECT week, day, count(wd.id) AS count FROM week_day wd GROUP BY wd.week, wd.day
```